# ¿Como puedo manipular los elementos de un array bidimensional? (JAVA)

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa que me dejaron en el Colegio, este trata sobre un tipo de tienda. En el cual primero tengo pedirle la cantidad de productos que tendrá, esta cantidad se enviara a otra clase donde esta tiene un **array bidimensional del tipo String**. En esta clase cree un constructor para inicializar el array, tenia mi código terminado pero mi Maestra dice que mi método **venderProducto** esta mal, ya que **si la cantidad es mayor a la existencia, la existencia no se debe de poner a 0, solamente no se debe hacer la venta**. Mi pregunta es, ¿como puedo manipular los elementos del array?, más bien como puedo realizar una suma o una resta de los productos desde la clase MAIN. Otro problema que note, es que cuando ingreso una cantidad para comprar y esta es más grande a la establecida, no me indica **que la cantidad ingresa es mayor a la que se quiere comprar**.  En mi código por ejemplo, en la **clase PRODUCTO**, las características de los productos las inicie con un **método set** de la siguiente manera:

```
public void setNombre(int i, String nombre) {
    producto[i][0] = nombre;
}

public void setCantidad(int i, int cantidad) {
    producto[i][1] = "" + cantidad;
}

public void setPrecio(int i, double precio) {
    producto[i][2] = "" + precio;
}
```

### Mi codigo

### Clase MAIN

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        Producto p1;
        boolean resp=false;
        int opc, opc2 = 0, n, cantidad;
        double precio;
        String producto;
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos productos tiene su tienda?");
        n = leer.nextInt();
        p1 = new Producto(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ");
            producto = leer.next();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el precio del producto: ");
            precio = leer.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad del producto: ");
            cantidad = leer.nextInt();
            p1.setNombre(i, producto);
            p1.setPrecio(i, precio);
            p1.setCantidad(i, cantidad);
        }
        do {
            System.out.println("1.- Vender");
            System.out.println("2.- Comprar");
            System.out.println("3.- Salir");
            opc = leer.nextInt();
            switch (opc) {
                case 1:
                    do {
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                            System.out.println((i + 1) + ".- " + p1.getNombre(i) + ", $: " + p1.getPrecio(i));
                        }
                        System.out.println((n + 1) + ".- Salir");
                        System.out.println("¿Que producto desea vender?");
                        opc2 = leer.nextInt();
                        opc2--;
                        if (opc2 >= 0 && opc2 < n) {
                            System.out.println("¿Que cantidad desea vender de " + p1.getNombre(opc2) + " ?");
                            cantidad = leer.nextInt();
                            p1.venderProducto(cantidad, opc2);
                            System.out.println("Se han vendido " + cantidad + " del producto " + p1.getNombre(opc2));
                        } else if (opc2 < 0 && opc2 > n) {
                            System.out.println("Error..........");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Listo.......");
                        }
                    } while (opc2 != n);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    do {
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                            System.out.println((i + 1) + ".- " + p1.getNombre(i) + ", $: " + p1.getPrecio(i));
                        }
                        System.out.println((n + 1) + ".- Salir");
                        System.out.println("¿Que producto desea comprar?");
                        opc2 = leer.nextInt();
                        opc2--;
                        if (opc2 >= 0 && opc2 < n) {
                            System.out.println("¿Cuantos productos desea comprar de " + p1.getNombre(opc2) + " ?");
                            cantidad = leer.nextInt();
                            p1.comprarProducto(cantidad, opc2);
                            System.out.println("Se han comprado " + cantidad + " del producto " + p1.getNombre(opc2));
                        } else if (opc2 < 0 && opc2 > n) {
                            System.out.println("Error..........");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Gracias por comprar.......");
                        }
                    } while (opc2 != n);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    resp = true;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!resp);
    }
}
```

### CLASE PRODUCTO

```
public class Producto {

    private String producto[][];

    Producto(int i) {
        producto = new String[i][3];
    }

    public void setNombre(int i, String nombre) {
        producto[i][0] = nombre;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int i, int cantidad) {
        producto[i][1] = "" + cantidad;
    }

    public void setPrecio(int i, double precio) {
        producto[i][2] = "" + precio;
    }

    public String getNombre(int i) {
        return producto[i][0];
    }

    public int getCantidad(int i) {
        return Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1]);
    }

    public double getPrecio(int i) {
        return Double.parseDouble(producto[i][2]);
    }

    public int venderProducto(int cantidad, int i) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1]) == 0 && Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1]) < cantidad) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1] = "" + (Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1]) - cantidad));
        }
    }

    public int comprarProducto(int cantidad, int i) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1]) == 0 && Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1]) < cantidad) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1] = "" + (Integer.parseInt(producto[i][1]) + cantidad));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El método venderProducto no debería retornar la existencia actual, debido a que, en ningún momento usas su valor al invocar el método. Lo que podrías hacer es que la rutina retorne true si la cantidad es mayor a la existencia actual, de lo contrario, false. Así detectas el error.

Comment: Hay muchas cosas que podrías (y deberías) mejorar en tu aplicación. Intenta separar la lógica de venta de la definición de tus clases. No es funcional poner un atributo *cantidad* a la clase *Producto*, rompe el principio de [Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), por mencionar alguno. Podrías crear una clase *Almacén* que si podría encargarse de manejar cantidades. También podrías crear una clase *Tienda* que sería la encargada de *vender* un producto. En fin, tienes el arroz, pero le falta sazón. Saludos

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por los consejos! :)